# Can you save recorded video to isolated storage on WP7

Tags: windows-phone-7

Can you save recorded video to isolated storage on Windows Phone 7? And if you can what is the best way to do it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Have you seen this "How to: Record Video in a Camera Application for Windows Phone" :-

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh394041(v=vs.92).aspx

Comment: This is a good link. In the future, always try Googling your question first (or Bing as the case may be).